# Does Objectify have an equivalent of Datastore.add() to insert non-existing entities only?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I would like to insert multiple entities (under the same entity group) into Datastore as a batch and only have the missing ones inserted and the rest unmodified. `Datastore.add(Entities...)` seems to support it as explained in this [client issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1339#issuecomment-256718812) and in the [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/datastore/package-summary.html).

I dont see an alternative on `ofy()` as the `save()` operation eventually converts into a `datastore.put()` as seen [here](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/WriteEngine.java#L78) which will overwrite all the entities.

The alternative would be to open a new transaction within which I can get these entities by their keys and find the missing ones from the list and insert them back but I am assuming that would be more expensive than the earlier option given that this transaction has a broader concurrency level than the row-level required with `add()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently, but it looks easy enough to support. Add a feature request at https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues